# Varied Load Testing Results on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter

Recently I have been performing load tests on our AWS environment using JMeter.

This works fine in practice however I have noticed varied results. For example - in the morning not too long after AWS has started up the load test will often fail. But if we re-run once or twice then the latencies appear to settle down and pass.

Additionally, I am not using an ELB or ASG with my instance. The instance has usually been up for at least 15 minutes prior to the load test running (everything green).

We are using a t2.medium instance and could it be that AWS allocates us more resources once it sees us receiving more traffic? Any suggestions on a better approach if this is the case?

Comment: Can you share a little bit more details (e.g. is there an ELB in front, are all instances InService and in green state when you start load test etc...)

Comment: Sure no problem, details added

Comment: Since you are using a t2 instance type, what do the CPU credits look like?

Comment: Just ran another load test which failed - the CPU credit usage jumped to 2.56. It also says I have 60+ credits available